# Handle multiple button click in View.OnClickListener in android

Tags: android

I have searched the internet and this site enough for the answer. I have also copy pasted the code from a couple of already posted answers on this site, but nothing has helped. There is no compile time error in my code. Hence I have created a fresh question..

I am using **Android Studio 0.4.4**. My complete code is as below. Please tell me where am i going wrong. It is giving a runtime error **"Sorry the application has stopped unexpectedly"** on the emulator and my HTC device.

```
package com.sample.controls;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Context;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
protected Button btnDialog;
final Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    btnDialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDialog);
    btnDialog.setOnClickListener(ClickListenerDelegate);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

private View.OnClickListener ClickListenerDelegate = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        if(v == MainActivity.this.btnDialog){
                /* Design Alert Dialog */
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setTitle("New Dialog Box")
                        .setMessage("Click OK to exit the app")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int which) {
                                MainActivity.this.finish();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int which) {
                                di.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                /* Create and show the Alert Dialog physically on screen */
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
};
}
```

Attached below is the log cat:

```
    02-17 20:35:58.547  30846-30846/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
    ComponentInfo{com.sample.controls/com.sample.controls.MainActivity}:
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2517) at
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2574)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1413)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sample.controls.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5195)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2473)
```

Attached is the fragment_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.sample.controls.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/strMsg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#f4b02f"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
        android:textColor="#750f12" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="24dp"
        android:typeface="sans" android:layout_margin="0dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Dialog"
        android:id="@+id/btnDialog"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp" android:layout_below="@+id/txtMessage"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#f4b02f" android:typeface="sans" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#71152b" android:width="200dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Attached is the activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.sample.controls.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Comment: Use `if(v.getId() == MainActivity.this.btnDialog.textview.getId())` for checking which button is clicked in `OnClickListener`  and also share logcat results if application is crashed to get more help

Comment: Logcat will surely have the actual error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to move context initialization inside `onCreate`

```
 Context context;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 context = this;  // initialize
```

coz you are using it in the below code

```
  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

Also

```
 private View.OnClickListener ClickListenerDelegate = new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v){
 switch(v.getId())
 {
    case R.id.btnDialog:
           // dialog button clicked
    break;
    case : R.id.secondbutton:
           // second button clicked
    break:
 } 
 }
 };
```

From your comment likely `btnDialog` is null. make sure its initialized properly

Button is in Fragment layout. So you need to initialize button in fragment's onCreate

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    btnDialog = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnDialog);
    btnDialog.setOnClickListener(ClickListenerDelegate);
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Hi Raghu, I tried what you have suggested, but still I am getting the same error message on my device and the emulator "Unfortunately, Test app has stopped.". Also wanna tell you that if I comment out the line "btnDialog.setOnClickListener(ClickListenerDelegate);" the app runs fine and displays the button on my screen. It means that something goes wrong when the ClickListenerDelegate is attached to the button. While debugging I saw "NullPointerException" being raised by the debugger and then eventually the error cropped up

Comment: @user3318752 post the xml layout. looks like `btnDialog` is null

Comment: Hi Raghu, I have posted the fragment_main.xml and activity_main.xml files above. Button is properly declared in the fragment_main.xml file... This file was automatically created by android studio and is like a layer over the activity_main.xml file.

Comment: @user3318752 Button is in fragment xml so you need to initialize button in framgent not in activity. Activity xml just has a framelayout. So this is the cause of the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @user3318752 look at the edit that is how you initialize button in fragment

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. My problem is solved now. However I have one last question regarding the same issue.. "PlaceHolderFragment" class was created as static by default. btnDialog.setOnClickListener(new ClickListenerDelegate()); was giving error "non static reference from a static class not possible." Hence I had to remove static from the PlaceHolderFragment declaration to make the code work. But if that class was made static by default by the IDE, then there must be some purpose of it. Hope I have not done anything wrong. I am just new to Android programming an it's API.

Comment: @user3318752 move your fragment to a different. java file. move the click listener for the button also to a different to that .java file, no need for static

Comment: Thanks much. This is exactly what I wanted to do.. Have a separate .java file for Click Listener so that the Main Activity class does not get cluttered.. It's working fine. However I have not created a separate file for the Fragment though. It still remains inside the Main Activity class.

Comment: @user3318752 remove the fragment in the activity class. everything else would be fine